# Connect to mysql phpMyAdmin database using propel in MacOS

Tags: mysql, composer-php, propel

I've been stuck with this problem for a couple of days now, and I can't seem to find any solution. I've installed XAMPP on my Mac, and everything seems to work fine with that. I also installed composer to use propel to connect to mysql and use a database I created using phpMyAdmin. Using the terminal, I moved to my project folder, since that's the one I installed composer on. I ran the command vendor/bin/propel init, selected mySql, and entered the database info, that is when I get stuck. 
Here it's a picture of all the multiple things I tried entering:
[image]

I've also tried changing the .my.cnf file multiple times. I've switched the socket to `/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql`, and that seems to connect after I ran `sudo/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start` but it seems to be connecting to a different database since the database name I'm looking for doesn't appear, and doesn't ask for passwords for users that need passwords.

[[image: In this picture]In this picture looks like I get connected but can't find the database I'm looking for[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL5jN.png)

[[image]]In this picture I don't specify any database name and can successfully connect[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJHze.png)

One final thing that I think is useful knowing is the output of the `ps -ax|grep mysql` command which is:
[image]

Any help solving this issue will be greatly appreciated! My guess is, that I have to switch the path to the right one.

Here are the results of running `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port' OR Variable_name = 'hostname'`

[image]

picture of all my databases:
[image]

picture of users:
[image]

Comment: `mysql --host=127.0.0.1`. Type `CREATE DATABASE demo;`. Exit out of that. Run your script again, using the choices that you made in the first run through.

Comment: But that is just creating a new database named demo, which I already created on phpMyAdmin which is the one I'm trying to access

Comment: Your first run through of your code says otherwise: `Unknown database 'demo'`

Comment: which means I'm not accessing my phpMyAdmin database because that interface shows all databases I've created, and demo is in there

Comment: You sure you're not accessing the mariadb instance, which is running on port 3307 by default in xampp?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is just an interface that communicates with a MySQL server. It's nothing more than a client, that connects to another server (Local or Remote). There's no such thing as "Connecting to phpMyAdmin". Perhaps you meant to say "Connecting to the database that phpMyAdmin is connecting to"?

Comment: Yes! As far as the mariadb looks like that's one I'm accessing since I added another db and tried accessing it, and it did

Comment: But I want to access the other db I created using phpMyAdmin

Comment: Run your composer again, and 127.0.0.1 with port 3307, and your script should work correctly.

Comment: it gives the error of connection refused :/

Comment: In phpMyAdmin (Where your demo database is), run the following MySQL query: `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port' OR Variable_name = 'hostname';` and post the results

Comment: Updated question with picture of results

Comment: The composer script, and the PHP server are both on the same computer, correct? When you access phpMyAdmin, you're doing so by going to `http://localhost/phpMyAdmin`, correct? If this is the case, please go into phpMyAdmin, and show me a list of your databases (Showing the demo database exists through phpMyAdmin)

Comment: Yes, everything on the same computer, and running through localhost, I added the picture that includes url and databses

Comment: check permissions for MySQL user `SHOW GRANTS 'root'@'localhost';` and `SHOW GRANTS 'root'@'127.0.0.1'`

Comment: Those 2 commands gave syntax errors but I uploaded a picture of all users and grants

Comment: Check if something is listening on the 3306 port `sudo ps aux | grep :3306` then check if it is mysql `sudo lsof -i :3306`